# Error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document in web service

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Can somebody help me? When I run it, it shows error on line 2 at column 1:

> Extra content at the end of the document.

Where did I go wrong? I'm still new to XML.

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("hospital");
  $user = $_GET['username'];
  $pass = $_GET['password'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM receptionist WHERE nama_receptionist = '$user'";

  $hasil = mysql_query($query);
  $data  = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);

  $password = $data['password'];


  if ($pass == $password) $response = "TRUE";
  else $response = "FALSE";

  header('Content-Type: text/xml');
  echo "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
  echo "<data>";
  echo "<response>".$response."</response>";
  echo "</data>";


  ?>
```

Comment: Please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm using the old xampp of version PHP 5.5 and I think everything works fine before I stated the xml inside the code

Comment: 'Everything' does not work fine. Although the code will execute, you will be wide open to SQL injection while running `mysql_`. That is to say, when you move to a production environment, people will easily be able to hack your database, and give themselves root-level access. You can prevent this with prepared statements, which are not available with the `mysql_` constructor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I suggest you switching over to MYSQLi, second, your `if` and `else` statements were missing `{}`, third, the code below should be helpful

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$user = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM receptionist WHERE nama_receptionist = '$user'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$password = $result['password'];

if ($pass == $password) {
    $response = "TRUE";
} else {
    $response = "FALSE"
}

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
echo "<data>";
echo "<response>".$response."</response>";
echo "</data>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks JeanPaul, but I got these error " Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array" Sorry I'm still new to php programming